# If statement search for string returns false but printed output displays string

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm using this function to search a site to see if a particular item i'm interested in s on sale. It first grabs the html from the page, then searches for an item i'm interested. When it finds the item it adds a number of the following lines (dictated by the rangenumber) to the variable 'endresult'. It then searches for the keyword ("sale") in endresult, at which point I'd like it to notify me if the keyword is present or not.
When I print endresult the output contains the keyword, but the if statement at the very end of the function always returns "keyword is missing" despite this and I can't work out why.

```
def bargainscraper(self, website, item, keyword,rangenum):
    request = urllib.request.Request(website)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()
    html = str(data)
    data1 = html2text.html2text(html)
    fw = open('result1.txt', 'w')
    fw.write(str(data1))
    fw.close()
    with open('result1.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if item in line:
                for x in range(rangenum):
                    endresult = str(f.readline())
                    print (endresult)
    if keyword in endresult:
        print("keyword is present")
    else:
        print("keyword is missing")
```

Comment: You're not adding lines to `endresult`. You're replacing it with each line you read, so it will only contain the last one. Printing its value at the end would make this clear.

Comment: HI interjay, How can I ensure endresult contains all of the lines?

Comment: @nph You can use some `list` to hold all the values of `endresult`. And later you can iterate over each `endresult` to match with `keyword`

Comment: @interjay Also, why does endresult show all the lines at the point I print it?

Comment: It seems to me that bash would be a lot more affective at this sort of thing than python.

Comment: You're printing it in a loop. On each iteration it contains a different line.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly need to concatenate the `endresult` instead of overwriting it with something like: `endresult += str(f.readline())` notice the "+" before the "=".

Comment: This doesn't work, I get an error saying 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'endresult' referenced before assignment'

Comment: you will have to add an `if` statement to check if `$endresult` is empty if it is then just use `=` if not then use `+=`.... another way would be to declare it as empty beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I found writing the endresult to a file within the for loop then searching that file for the keyword outside of the for loop was the answer I was looking for:

```
def bargainscraper(self, website, item, keyword,rangenum):
                request = urllib.request.Request(website)
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
                data = response.read()
                html = str(data)
                data1 = html2text.html2text(html)
                fw = open('result1.txt', 'w')
                fw.write(str(data1))
                fw.close()
                with open('result1.txt', 'r') as f:
                        for line in f:
                                if item in line:
                                        for x in range(rangenum):
                                                endresult = str(f.readline())
                                                # the 'a' switch is used to append
                                                with open('result2.txt', 'a') as n:
                                                        n.write(endresult)
                # This is outside of the for loop as otherwise it will iterate for each line of the rangenum
                if keyword in open('result2.txt').read():
                        print ("keyword is present")
                else:
                        print ("keyword is missing")
```